# Widgets in django forms are not working... What shall I do?

Tags: python, django

Without widgets form works correctly. It must be simple solution without calling super.**init**. In documentation it is exactly as I wrote here...

My views.py:

```
class ForumForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Forum
        fields = ['publisher', 'topic', 'text', 'date']

        widgets = {
            'publisher': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'topic': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'text': Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'date': DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

My model.py:

```
class Forum(models.Model):
    publisher = models.CharField('Публикатор', max_length=50, default='Anonymous')
    topic = models.CharField('Название', max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField('Текст')
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    comment = models.CharField('Комментарий', max_length=100, default='Комментарий')
    # slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, default='default')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пост'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Посты'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.topic
```

My template:

```
{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}

{% block title %}New form{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

The html file just shows the name of publisher: 'Публикатор'

Comment: `publisher` is a `ForeignKey`? Can you share your model?

Comment: your widgets looks fine. what do you mean by not working correctly? what happened when you add widgets? Could you update in your question? also as Willem suggested, please put models.py, views and your template

Comment: if it is just style that is not rendering, maybe tray to clear browser history.

Comment: @ha-neul here it is, I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should stat the "forms." in front of each line.

For example:
forms.TextInput(attrs=...

Also use forms.ModelForm

Comment: This is only the case if you did not import the identifiers explicitly, like `from django.forms import TextInput, ModelForm, DateTimeInput`

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem this would not work? class ForumForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Forum
        fields = ['publisher', 'topic', 'text', 'date']

        widgets = {
            'publisher': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'topic':  forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'text':  forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'date':  forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }